# Top & left css values are not working in my code

Tags: html, css

The `top` & the `left` css values in my code are not working. I've applied them to an `h1` but, their not working and I don't know why. Here is all of my code. I've been trying to see what's wrong for a really long time. Please tell me if you spot a problem. And thank you for looking at my post.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #171a1f;
}

h1.TxT {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  color: #ffa600;
} // here is where the code is not working

.search-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #2f3640;
  height;
  40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.search-box:hover>.search-txt {
  width: 240px;
  padding: 0 6px;
}

.search-btn {
  color: #ffa600;
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  height 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: ;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.search-txt {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="search-style.css">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
  <title>Searchbar Test</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1 class="TxT">Search</h1>
  <div class="search-box">
    <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="" placeholder="Type to search">
    <a class="search-btn" href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try adding ```position:relative;``` to both your ```h1``` and its parent, could help. Or explain what your expected result looks like, "are not working" or "is wrong" is a bit vague.

Answer (score 2):

There were a couple of small errors affecting your code. The first was that you had a colon instead of a semi-colon in the `height` css. Also there was no background attribute set in the background of the search btn (I commented it out)
The main thing, however, was that your comment was formatted so that the search-box class was not being picked up. Instead of using 2 forward slashes in css, surround your comments with `/*` and `*/` - asterisk and and forward slashes.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #171a1f;
}

h1.TxT {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  color: #ffa600;
} /* here is where the code is not working*/

.search-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #2f3640;
  height:40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.search-box:hover>.search-txt {
  width: 240px;
  padding: 0 6px;
}

.search-btn {
  color: #ffa600;
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  height 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
 /* background:*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.search-txt {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="search-style.css">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
  <title>Searchbar Test</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1 class="TxT">Search</h1>
  <div class="search-box">
    <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="" placeholder="Type to search">
    <a class="search-btn" href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the syntax errors for the comment in the CSS code: For `top` and `left` parameters to work (for that `h1` element), the element needs to have `position: relative` ( or `absolute` or `fixed`, but those will also affect the position in other ways, so you'll most likely need relative position)